# Autodesk Forge Heroku Deployment

Tags: heroku, autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

I followed this tutorial all along https://learnforge.autodesk.io/#/tutorials/modifymodels.
In local I haven't seen any error but when I try to deploy this app to the Heroku with the guide of the tutorial, app doesn't work appropriately. Just viewer app does work both HEROKU and Local. In local we use ngrok for testing purpose but I believe it is not necessary in web deployment. What am I doing wrong.
I deployed this sample to https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation but no luck.
App upload and receive the file after it says 'workitem itemid started', app do nothing all along. After a long time server give 1006 error. Any help appreciated. By the way this is my first post, sorry if it is too long

Comment: Did you update your callback url to match your heroku app one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this for your webhook url.

```
FORGE_WEBHOOK_URL: "http://APP_NAME.herokuapp.com
```

Comment: Thanks you so much. I just realized. How can I be so blind?